# what does "env TEXINPUTS= ... " mean?

Tags: cmake, tex

I'm parsing a project with many tests. I am stacked with parsing `CMakeLists.txt` file. Essentially in the second line in downstream **add_test()** construction:

```
add_test(test_tex_${_tex_file_name}
     env TEXINPUTS=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_tex
     ${TEX_EXECUTABLE} ${TEXPP_EXECUTABLE} ${_tex_file})
set_property(TEST test_tex_${_tex_file_name} PROPERTY TIMEOUT 30)
```

This program have a relationship to TeX. So I don't understand the meaning of the second line

```
env TEXINPUTS=...
```

Please, could someone explain me what does it mean. It would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [`env`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) command is used to control the environment.  With no arguments, it simply prints the current environment.  With the `-i` option, it cancels all the existing environment, adding whatever is specified in the `env` arguments.  Without the `-i` option and with some `VAR=value` arguments, plus a command (with optional arguments), then the command is run with the environment variables added to, or overriding, the environment.  (If there's no command but there are environment variables, then the environment is printed with the extra variables set.)

So much for the general theory.  In the question, you have:

```
add_test(test_tex_${_tex_file_name}
     env TEXINPUTS=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_tex
     ${TEX_EXECUTABLE} ${TEXPP_EXECUTABLE} ${_tex_file})
```

Unless the lines there are flattened into a single line, the `env` does nothing.  Put bluntly, if the `env TEXINPUTS=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` doesn't do much unless there are spaces in the value of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.  It will print the environment with the extra variable TEXINPUTS set to the value of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.  If the lines are flattened, then the `test_tex` command would be run with some extra arguments, and with `TEXINPUTS` set to the value.